# Trello API: How to Get Card's Creator Information

Tags: api, trello

I was in a need to get creator information who actually created a card. Usually trello has actions associated with any event and that event contains the information who actually has performed that action. I was unable to find any resource to find the solution.

Answer (score 7):

After struggling a bit, I was able to find a solution. You atleast have to have card's id to find its creator and thats obvious. So now you can peform the following set of operations:

1. Get the card-id
2. By card-id, get its board-id
3. Then get all actions of this board by applying appropriate filters. e.g.

   https://api.trello.com/1/boards/<board_id>/actions?key=<api_key>&token=<access_token>&filter=createCard&fields=idMemberCreator&idModels=<card_id>

Answer (score 1):

> I was in a need to get creator information who actually created a card

Do you have access to the UI? Then you only need to add `.json` to the end of the url and start digging.

> Find `"memberCreator" : { ... "username": "I am the creator" ... }` object

Answer (score 1):

Add to @Karl Pokus 's answer

The json is quire large. Find `"memberCreator" : { "username": "The Name" }` object.